# Finding continuous repetition of numbers in an array in each column using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, repeat, counting

I have a real time temperature log from 8 stations for scientific studies.
Whenever all 8 stations have acquired data , it is pushed in an array of 8 columns.

e.g.  the following table

```
  Time1    22  26  18  12  20  15  ..   for 8 stations

  Time2   20  26  15  13  20  18...

  Time3   19  28  17  15  20  16 ...
```

Time1 is the most recent data tag ...   Time2 is previous one an so on.

Here 26 is repeated 2 times in station #2

```
 20 is repeated 3 times in station #5
```

So the expected output is similar to the above 2 sentences.

I am not a regular ( learned ) .js programmer but can adapt the code in main routine running on the system.

Is there a  way to signal a repeat of temperature for a station and how many times?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you actually storing the previous arrays in any form?  Or simply logging them to the console?

Comment: where are you storing the data? can we suppose they are store in an array of arrays?

Comment: As every station transmits the data , first it is used to fill a 8 bit array  and when it is full it is pushed to the main database which I had reproduced in the OP.  This database is accessible to users like me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite the algorithm and surely it can be simpler, but here's how I did it.

Create a 2d array with the times and temperatures. The parent array will be `times` and the child arrays will be the `temperatures` per `station`. Each child array has 8 entries. Each position in that child array indicates the `station`.

First you've got to transform the data and create sets of `temperatures` per `station`.

```
[
  [22, 20, 19],
  [26, 26, 28],
  [18, 15, 17],
  ...
]
```

Loop over the new set and count how many duplicates of `temperatures` are in each station array. Turn each station array in an object in which you keep count.

```
[
  {
    "22": 1,
    "20": 1,
    "19": 1,
  },
  {
    "26": 2,
    "28": 1,
  },
  {
    "18": 1,
    "15": 1,
    "17": 1,
  },
  ...
]
```

Now filter out any counts per station that is lower than `1`, because you only want duplicates. And also put everything in a new array that also passes the number of the `station` in a new array.

```
[
  [
    2,
    {
      "26": 2
    }
  ],
  ...
]
```

From here you know that station `2` has recorded the temperature `26` `2` times. And you can put that all together in a string by looping over the result.

Run the snippet below to see it running.

```js
// Make sure that your temp recordings are in a single array with
// arrays inside of it.
// Each position (left -> right) marking the index of the station.
const times = [
  [22, 26, 18, 12, 20, 17, 18, 19],
  [20, 26, 15, 13, 20, 18, 18, 20],
  [19, 28, 17, 15, 20, 16, 15, 18]
];

const getRepeatedTempsPerStation = times => {
  // Get longest length of times array.
  const length = Math.max(...times.map(time => time.length));

  // Create a new array with the temps per station.
  const tempsPerStation = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    tempsPerStation[i] = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < times.length; j++) {
      tempsPerStation[i].push(times[j][i]);
    }
  }
  
  // Per station count how many times a single temp occurs.
  const countsPerStation = tempsPerStation.map(temps => 
    temps.reduce((acc, temp) => {
      acc[temp] = (acc[temp] || 0) + 1;
      return acc;
    }, {})
  );
    
  // Give each set of counts the number of the station and 
  // filter out all stations without any duplicate numbers.
  const stationsWithRepeatedTemps = countsPerStation
    .map((counts, index) => [index + 1, Object.fromEntries(
      Object.entries(counts).filter(([temp, count]) => 
        count > 1 && !isNaN(temp))
    )])
    .filter(([station, counts]) => Object.keys(counts).length > 0);
  
  return stationsWithRepeatedTemps;
}

// Get the result.
const results = getRepeatedTempsPerStation(times);

// Loop over the result and output it in a string.
for (const [station, tempCounts] of results) {
  for (const [temp, count] of Object.entries(tempCounts)) {
    console.log(`${temp} is repeated ${count} times in station #${station}`);
  }
}
```

This snippet also checks if any item in the array of sets is not a number, so in case some data doesn't come through and `null` is passed, you're good.

Comment: Oh God!   I was expecting something tomorrow or a day after.  but in less than an hour ..     simply overwhelming..   Thanks Emiel